# Hardware requirements for node

Tags: staking

Would Raspberry Pi 4 with 4GB with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Is that enough to get started running the test mode?

Answer (score 4):

As per the last release of [cardano-node](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases).

Minimum System Requirements:

- An Intel or AMD x86 processor with two or more cores, at 1.6GHz or faster (2GHz or faster for a stake pool or relay)
- 16GB of RAM
- 120GB of free storage (200GB recommended for future growth)

However, you might get away with your setup, but do not be surprised if not :)

Answer (score 3):

I run PGWAD pool on raspberrypi 4.
There is an alliance of pool operators running on raspberry pi.
You can find details here https://armada-alliance.com/
There are guides to help you setup pool.

Answer (score 0):

I run a cardano-node 1.27.0 relay on a Pi4 8GB, and the RAM is often used at around 7-7.5GB.

My x86 relay is now compiled to cardano-node 1.29.0 and after 12 hours seems to be running around 5GB, so perhaps some memory optimizations are in there.

Try it.  If you are just missing enough RAM, maybe zRAM can help.